# How to fix Nativescript Ios app crash after splash screen?

Tags: nativescript

I've got a Nativescript-Vue iOS app that works perfectly in the simulator.

When I deploy it to the Apple App Store, to test using TestFlight, the build and uploads work fine. But when I execute the app on a real device (iPhone 6s or iPad Air, both running the latest iOS version) the splash screen shows, then the app crashes.

I've tried almost every permutation of settings I can think of, but so far all versions crash after the splash screen.  I suspect that it's something to do with signing/provisioning since the app works fine in the simulator.

Any ideas/suggestions as to how to get past this would be very much appreciated, since I'm at a loss.  I suspect that the Apple App Store/TestFlight publishing process has worms. ;-)

I'm not new to development (got decades of experience) but fairly new to Nativescript and IOS app development.

Thanks!

tns info shows:

```
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 6.1.2 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-core-modules has 6.1.1 version and is up to date.
⚠ Update available for component tns-android. Your current version is 6.1.1 and the latest available version is 6.1.2.
✔ Component tns-ios has 6.1.1 version and is up to date.
```

MacOS Mojave 10.14.4 (running in a VMWare virtual machine).

Latest NodeJS/NPM, and XCode v10.2.1

I've tried including my Distribution provisioning profile in build.xconfig and also specifying it on the build command:

```sh
tns build ios --release --for-device --provision xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
```

Builds fine....no errors and I end up with an ipa that uploads fine.

I then deploy to the app store for testing using TestFlight using:

```sh
 tns publish ios --ipa platforms/ios/build/Release-iphoneos/mobile.ipa --appleApplicationSpecificPassword xxx-xxx-xxx-xx --appleSessionBase64 xxxxxxxxx
```

Uploads fine....passes all tests and becomes available through TestFlight fine.

I've also tried building/uploading using XCode which works fine, but still the app crashes after the splash screen on a real device.

Here is the first part of the crash log from my iPhone:

```
{"app_name":"mobile","app_cohort":"2|date=1569609000000&sf=143455&tid=61b35e66f4d79f0304b4f4b7164b8363d323e055c604cd261fe8b2b673d2f72b&ttype=i","app_version":"1.0","timestamp":"2019-09-27 14:39:36.59 -0400","slice_uuid":"5f391bac-b299-3711-a064-11adaf34562a","adam_id":1481012502,"build_version":"1.0.6","bundleID":"ca.oftr.trailmaps","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.1 (17A844)","incident_id":"5EF5270B-ABF0-4A95-A2B1-B37CAA157B7D","is_beta":true,"name":"mobile"}
Incident Identifier: 5EF5270B-ABF0-4A95-A2B1-B37CAA157B7D
Beta Identifier:     2AA29AA5-AACE-4595-840B-C862C240BC59
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Process:             mobile [1023]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/96251F76-540E-4140-A35D-619EDF113FDD/mobile.app/mobile
Identifier:          ca.oftr.trailmaps
Version:             1.0.6 (1.0)
AppStoreTools:       11A1002b
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           ca.oftr.trailmaps [675]


Date/Time:           2019-09-27 14:39:36.0120 -0400
Launch Time:         2019-09-27 14:39:34.3645 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.1 (17A844)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    7.00.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1ad8d898c 0x1ad6010a4 0x102b13808 0x102b49e5c 0x10365d3c4 0x1036601b4 0x1ad83409c 0x1ad8340e4 0x1ad833444 0x1ad8330fc 0x1ad7af43c 0x1ad832a4c 0x1adb8f2d8 0x1b18dd5a4 0x1b18e34c0 0x1b10bf810 0x1b15503ec 0x1b10c02f8 0x1b10bfd50 0x1b10c0124 0x1b10bf9e0 0x1b10c3efc 0x1b1483028 0x1b15695ac 0x1b10c3c34 0x1b15694a8 0x1b10c3aa0 0x1b0f38efc 0x1b0f37a64 0x1b0f38c34 0x1b18e1840 0x1b14a3a0c 0x1b2970994 0x1b2995960 0x1b297b0f8 0x1b299561c 0x1ad5a6184 0x1ad54f038 0x1b29ba540 0x1b29ba20c 0x1b29ba734 0x1ad8567e0 0x1ad856738 0x1ad855f20 0x1ad85101c 0x1ad8508bc 0x1b76bb328 0x1b18e56d4 0x103660044 0x10365cae4 0x10365c5e0 0x102ad4f90 0x10365b7e8 0x103659b64 0x103659b64 0x103659b64 0x103659b64 0x103659b64 0x103659b64 0x103659b64 0x103659b64 0x103659ac4 0x103659b64 0x10364560c 0x1032cd658 0x1034a5ffc 0x102aee148 0x102c571b0 0x10365b54c 0x103659b64 0x103659b64 0x10364560c 0x1032cd658 0x1034a61c8 0x102c507d0 0x102ae4570 0x102b58564 0x1022af420 0x1ad6db460)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ad6d0ebc 0x1ad6ac000 + 151228
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad5ec790 0x1ad5ea000 + 10128
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001ad540824 0x1ad4cd000 + 473124
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ad6997d4 0x1ad698000 + 6100
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ad6999c4 0x1ad698000 + 6596
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ad601358 0x1ad5fb000 + 25432
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ad6a6304 0x1ad698000 + 58116
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ad6a5c58 0x1ad698000 + 56408
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ad6a5c18 0x1ad698000 + 56344
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ad6011d0 0x1ad5fb000 + 25040
10  NativeScript                    0x0000000102b13808 0x102acc000 + 292872
11  NativeScript                    0x0000000102b49e5c 0x102acc000 + 515676
12  NativeScript                    0x000000010365d3c4 0x102acc000 + 12129220
13  NativeScript                    0x00000001036601b4 0x102acc000 + 12140980
14  NativeScript                    0x00000001036601b4 0x102acc000 + 12140980
15  NativeScript                    0x00000001036601b4 0x102acc000 + 12140980
16  NativeScript                    0x00000001036601b4 0x102acc000 + 12140980
17  NativeScript                    0x00000001036601b4 0x102acc000 + 12140980
18  NativeScript                    0x00000001036601b4 0x102acc000 + 12140980
19  NativeScript                    0x00000001036601b4 0x102acc000 + 12140980
20  NativeScript                    0x00000001036601b4 0x102acc000 + 12140980
21  NativeScript                    0x00000001036601b4 0x102acc000 + 12140980
22  NativeScript                    0x00000001036601b4 0x102acc000 + 12140980
23  NativeScript                    0x00000001036601b4 0x102acc000 + 12140980
```

The Nativescript line repeats for 500+ lines. Then I see:

```
Thread 1 name:  JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ad6d0c8c 0x1ad6ac000 + 150668
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad5ee204 0x1ad5ea000 + 16900
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001ad722840 0x1ad714000 + 59456
3   NativeScript                    0x0000000102b8cbe4 0x102acc000 + 789476
4   NativeScript                    0x0000000102b8ca94 0x102acc000 + 789140
5   NativeScript                    0x0000000102b8b678 0x102acc000 + 783992
6   NativeScript                    0x0000000102b8acec 0x102acc000 + 781548
7   NativeScript                    0x0000000102b8c7ac 0x102acc000 + 788396
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad5f51ec 0x1ad5ea000 + 45548
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad5f8aec 0x1ad5ea000 + 60140

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad5f8ad8 0x1ad5ea000 + 60120

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad5f8ad8 0x1ad5ea000 + 60120

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad5f8ad8 0x1ad5ea000 + 60120

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad5f8ad8 0x1ad5ea000 + 60120

Thread 6 name:  Heap Helper Thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ad6d0c8c 0x1ad6ac000 + 150668
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad5ee204 0x1ad5ea000 + 16900
2   NativeScript                    0x0000000102ba2310 0x102acc000 + 877328
3   NativeScript                    0x0000000102b9da10 0x102acc000 + 858640
4   NativeScript                    0x0000000103271cf0 0x102acc000 + 8019184
5   NativeScript                    0x0000000102b8e600 0x102acc000 + 796160
6   NativeScript                    0x0000000102ba0744 0x102acc000 + 870212
7   NativeScript                    0x0000000102ba1b30 0x102acc000 + 875312
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad5f51ec 0x1ad5ea000 + 45548
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad5f8aec 0x1ad5ea000 + 60140

Thread 7 name:  JSC Heap Collector Thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ad6d0c8c 0x1ad6ac000 + 150668
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad5ee204 0x1ad5ea000 + 16900
2   NativeScript                    0x0000000102ba2310 0x102acc000 + 877328
3   NativeScript                    0x0000000102b9da10 0x102acc000 + 858640
4   NativeScript                    0x0000000103271cf0 0x102acc000 + 8019184
5   NativeScript                    0x0000000102b8e600 0x102acc000 + 796160
6   NativeScript                    0x0000000102ba0744 0x102acc000 + 870212
7   NativeScript                    0x0000000102ba1b30 0x102acc000 + 875312
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad5f51ec 0x1ad5ea000 + 45548
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad5f8aec 0x1ad5ea000 + 60140

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ad6af5f4 0x1ad6ac000 + 13812
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ad6aea60 0x1ad6ac000 + 10848
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ad856068 0x1ad7ad000 + 692328
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ad851188 0x1ad7ad000 + 672136
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ad8508bc 0x1ad7ad000 + 669884
5   Foundation                      0x00000001adb90994 0x1adb89000 + 31124
6   Foundation                      0x00000001adb90874 0x1adb89000 + 30836
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b197d49c 0x1b0ef5000 + 11043996
8   Foundation                      0x00000001adcc10b0 0x1adb89000 + 1278128
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad5f51ec 0x1ad5ea000 + 45548
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad5f8aec 0x1ad5ea000 + 60140

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x00000001ad6a95d8   x5: 0x000000016db522c0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000102a59800   x9: 0x00000001ad5f0b5c  x10: 0x00000001ad5ec720  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x00000001e422b080  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000002
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000507  x21: 0x000000016db522c0  x22: 0x0000000102a598e0  x23: 0x000000010367b495
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x000000016db537e0  x27: 0x00000001e9a2b9a0
   x28: 0x0000000000000001   fp: 0x000000016db52220   lr: 0x00000001ad5ec790
    sp: 0x000000016db52200   pc: 0x00000001ad6d0ebc cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
0x1022a8000 - 0x1022affff mobile arm64  <5f391bacb2993711a06411adaf34562a> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/96251F76-540E-4140-A35D-619EDF113FDD/mobile.app/mobile
0x1027d0000 - 0x10281bfff SocketIO arm64  <beb5044ed4233fdc974ed73fee4bf1c9> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/96251F76-540E-4140-A35D-619EDF113FDD/mobile.app/Frameworks/SocketIO.framework/SocketIO
0x1028b4000 - 0x1028dffff Starscream arm64  <7e6a5107d333347bb22abb3e9d48ef0d> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/96251F76-540E-4140-A35D-619EDF113FDD/mobile.app/Frameworks/Starscream.framework/Starscream
0x10293c000 - 0x102947fff Toast arm64  <2a50d9d655243c28a7f4c5fab69b53dd> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/96251F76-540E-4140-A35D-619EDF113FDD/mobile.app/Frameworks/Toast.framework/Toast
0x10295c000 - 0x102963fff TNSWidgets arm64  <fde1bcbc250834e0928be366e6e442f3> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/96251F76-540E-4140-A35D-619EDF113FDD/mobile.app/Frameworks/TNSWidgets.framework/TNSWidgets
0x1029f0000 - 0x102a53fff dyld arm64  <571392a7e1e6369f8805c1a141f3c1c5> /usr/lib/dyld
0x102acc000 - 0x1037bbfff NativeScript arm64  <a85f51cba55e35f2b076c503bfe23a88> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/96251F76-540E-4140-A35D-619EDF113FDD/mobile.app/Frameworks/NativeScript.framework/NativeScript
0x103b14000 - 0x103eb7fff Mapbox arm64  <01ae5a1ef2b1340288539b7ec8d61378> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/96251F76-540E-4140-A35D-619EDF113FDD/mobile.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox
0x103fcc000 - 0x103fd7fff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64  <048eb53f47913e0a9314876c6577aa10> /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
0x1ad483000 - 0x1ad499fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <f7e5141b7c243e5aaa79065004ecbf30> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x1ad49a000 - 0x1ad4cbfff libxpc.dylib arm64  <217dc1a778213f1fa8373825d770ef05> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x1ad4cc000 - 0x1ad4ccfff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <c06042b841f63e4994717b606330928a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x1ad4cd000 - 0x1ad549fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <c4beb94cb8313889a4034b7a4aa4dcdf> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1ad54a000 - 0x1ad5befff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <3a5db4e0bc24375d897e51e6cf7d6304> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1ad5bf000 - 0x1ad5defff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <5dbcbc6428083e64890cb59f2ddfeb1d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x1ad5df000 - 0x1ad5e9fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <09a51269d3c53ece87b7f32c096af8e7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x1ad5ea000 - 0x1ad5fafff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <c3fa4f34750f362bbefe835bfb15c0f8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1ad5fb000 - 0x1ad62bfff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <b39048c383953de4af4daca3097fdc53> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1ad62c000 - 0x1ad697fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <6ddbd01331ce32cb9fce3c5f40880ac5> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x1ad698000 - 0x1ad6abfff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <b148bc1f83c834e2868d00db2d9bbb55> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1ad6ac000 - 0x1ad6d9fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <92cbd0cb514f3a23a21c169e915052a7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x1ad6da000 - 0x1ad70bfff libdyld.dylib arm64  <3a812c9416333a559831b451e9a59f3c> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x1ad70c000 - 0x1ad713fff libsystem_darwin.dylib arm64  <c10d7897c5833454b6f9697c78d9eeb6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
0x1ad714000 - 0x1ad76afff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <4547c800a6533ece9808c26768583e25> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x1ad76b000 - 0x1ad7acfff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <bb4a834b619136be866b5018d4eb692d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
```

remainder of log redacted.

Comment: Did you try the debugging (`tns debug`) directly on device?

Comment: I can't do that at the moment.  Running MacOS in a virtual machine and connecting an iOS device locks up the VM (known issue). I'm trying to find a physical MacOS device to allow me to do such debugging, but that might take a while....trying to avoid paying the "Apple Tax" since I'm not invested in that architecture.

Comment: A friend has a MacOS laptop that he's gonna lend me for testing.....so once I get that in hand, I'll try using tns debug to see if it sheds any more light as to what is causing this crash.

Comment: did you got any solution? @PurpleBeast